# pdflatex does not overwrite existing PDF files upon compilation when using TikZ external

Tags: tikz-pgf, external-files, tikz-external

I have a LaTeX/`pgf`/TikZ file that I'm trying to compile. I included the library `external` so that I could export the file. However, the problem is that `\tikzexternalize` apparently doesn't have a command to overwrite existing files from previous compilations. So, my compiled things only get saved if I delete the originals first. That's really tedious, and not normal TeX behavior anyway. How do I get it to overwrite them automatically?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). You could have a look to the pgfmanual to the `force remake` key.